# How do i show a full HEX in string?

Tags: hex

how do i show full HEX in string, such as 000010, but not just only 10.
i have to show 0000 in front of the 10.
here is my code... thanks =)

```
bn1 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(strm1, 16), 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following after the line of code you provided:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6 - bn1.Length; i++)
    bn1 = "0" + bn1;
```

Note that this is a very simple method, just to show the idea.